# Cordova - Display captured Image

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, camera

I wrote code with that I can capture an image. Now I want to show the picture in the app. I just want to create a div-container with the id "capturedImage".

This is my code, which takes a picture, and works fine:

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {


}

function captureImage() {
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess1, captureError1, { limit: 1 });
}

function captureSuccess1(mediaFiles) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < mediaFiles.length; i++) {
        var path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        alert(path);
        document.getElementById('capturedPicture').src = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
    }
}

function captureError1(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
    alert(msg);
}
```

I thought I could display the picture with the following code, but that is not possible.

```
document.getElementById('capturedPicture').src = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
```

Do you have some idea what might be wrong?

Comment: had you found any error in console ?

Comment: What does path variable shows ?

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('capturedPicture'))[0].src = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
```

Use this to set the src of the image element

Comment: can i use a command of angular that easy or do i have to install something?

Comment: it doesnt, work, i made the change and i cant see the picture in the html-site

Comment: which html element are you using to display the image? .src will work only in a <img> element

Comment: WAIT, now it works, i thank you so much that you helped me!! can you say how i can scale the picture? <3

Comment: `angular.element(document.getElementById('capturedPicture'))[0].style.width = '120px'`

Comment: You can adjust the height and width like this

Comment: thank you but that command doesnt work. also
angular.element(document.getElementById('capturedPicture'))[0].src = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
does not work, i have used
document.getElementById('capturedPicture').src = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
instead and it worked.
when i use your version, then he does no start the camera